# Adding Text after every line on the same cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Excel cells:

```
D001
D002
D003
345
```

(In the same cell)

I need to add a string of text after every line on the same cell, like this:

```
D001 First Text
D0002 Second Text
D003 Third Text
345 Fouth Text
```

I found a code which allows me to count how many lines there are on the same cell, but I dont find any way of using it to write after the text on each of those lines:

```
Public Sub CountLines()
Dim H1 As Double
Dim H2 As Double
Dim row As Long

row = 1
While Cells(row, 1).Value <> ""
    With Cells(row, 1)
        .WrapText = False
        H1 = .height
        .WrapText = True
        H2 = .height
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = H2 / H1
    End With
    row = row + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

I guess the right way of doing it is by using a For to write text before any change of line he finds (Ch(10)) on VBA, but i havent been able to make it work

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

### Adding Text To Count Line Breaks

**This code will loop through all cells with any value in Column A. 
I have recreated your data set in my Excel:**

[image]

**The code will break up each line, add which line it is, and move on to the next:**

[image]

**Below is the code:**

```
Sub AddText()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim myCell As Variant, myRange As Range, tempArr() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set myRange = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    For Each myCell In myRange
        tempArr = Split(myCell, Chr(10))
        myCell.Value = ""
        For i = 0 To UBound(tempArr)
            tempArr(i) = tempArr(i) & " text " & i
            If i = UBound(tempArr) Then
                myCell.Value = myCell.Value & tempArr(i)
            Else: myCell.Value = myCell.Value & tempArr(i) & Chr(10)
            End If
        Next i
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

---

If you want it to count from base 1 instead of base 0, change the lines `myCell.Value = myCell.Value & tempArr(i)` (and the following one in the If statement) to `myCell.Value = myCell.Value & tempArr(i) + 1`

---

I should mention again that this is already set up for a dynamic range in Column A. Meaning if you add more data formatted the same way in `A2`, the code will apply itself to that as well, all the way to the last set of data in column A.

Comment: `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)` would return a single cell range.    `ReDim Preserve tempArr(LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr))` isn't necessary. Finally I believe that OP asked for the user to use a text to be added array of his choice instead of simply "Text1", Text2" ...

Comment: On the first one you're totally right. I forgot the first part of the range. On the second part, I'll be honest, I don't know when or when not to ReDim an array, so any time I use it's UBound or LBound as variables, I always ReDim it to be safe. On the last one, the OP did give a sample output, but in my experience on this site, no one wants something that simple. Usually they want to be able to have dynamic inputs that range into the hundreds or thousands. That being the case, it's unreasonable to build an array of `First Text, Second Text, etc...`. If he doesn't like it, someone else might.

Comment: Sorry if I havent explained enough, the Text I'd add on the right of every line, is the name of the code that I take from another Sheet:
D001 Bikes
D002 Computers
Doo3 Camels
Etc...

Thats why I wanted something to be able to after everytime it gets a LineChange on the cell, be able to open a For and find the right text to add according to the code (D001, for example, that part is already coded, I wasnt able to find a way to write next to every code, Thanks

Comment: `ReDim` array when you're going to change its size, for instance when you have to add or remove new "slots" (and in that case you mostly want to add `Preserve` keyword not to loose actual content). In this case you were simply "confirming" the array as it already was, thus uselessly. Not too sure about your last issue comment. I can add that but the OP question showed different texts for different lines so I argued he must take those texts out of a "list", as an array could be. and you can fast build an array out of a large `Range`

Comment: @Joan Ruize, your actual question narrative doesn't mention what you said in your last comment. you may want to first choose the answer that best fits your _actual_ question narrative and then, if you still need something more, post a new question

Comment: @user3598756 So even though my array may change it's size on future iterations, I still wouldn't need that? Rather, as long as I'm injecting an array return into the array (such as Split()), I don't need to confirm the array size, it does it automatically?

Comment: @JoanRuize Have one of us given you the answer you were looking for? If not, please elaborate on your question so we can get you closer to what you need. Or start a new question.

Comment: I'm still unable to make it work, Ill still keep trying to use  the solucions you've given to me altogether with my code and see if I can somehow do it. Otherwise I'll try to be more specifical with my needs, sorry if it is not clear enough as it is, English is not my native language and my brain looks like yogurt after a couple hours of trying to make this thing work. THanks for the help and interest on it

Comment: @JoanRuize; please give each answer the reason why it doesn't work, so that each answerer can elaborate on its own issues

Comment: @Tyeler, I can't see where in your code `tempArr` changes its size

Comment: @user3598756 say cell A1 has 4 lines that get broken up into the array, and cell A2 has 8 lines. Wouldn't that change the array size? Or since I'm not adding to/subtracting from the array, I'm completely reassigning the values to it, it's not actually _changing the size_ of `tempArr`, but just resetting it?

Comment: @user3598756 I think I get what you're saying now. That does make sense.

Comment: @Tyeler, I guess you already got there but every time you process a new cell you build `tempArr` anew with the `Split()` function so that it gets automatically correctly sized

Answer (score 0):

Dim arr() As String
Dim arr2() As String

arr = Split(yourCell, char(10))
arr2 = Split("first, second, third", "," )

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
debug. print arr(i) + arr2(i) 
next i

after rebuilding the new string the new string assign it back to the cell

Comment: this doesn't handle the case of different array sizes

Comment: i dont know of a function that gets a number and returns third for 3 or tenth for 10...these values should be manually written

Comment: I mean that there may be the case when cell content is a N lines string while additional text array can have less than N elements. In this case the for loop would error out at `arr2(i)` when i exceeds `arr2` upper bound

Comment: yes you are right. it ca be solved with if statement if i<=3 use array else i + "th"... with code a lot can be achived...  the chalenge is to understand what is the need :)

Answer (score 0):

This will only place (random) text after each line in the cell. But it gives you a place to start.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RePrint()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set MyRange = Range("A1")
MyArray = Split(MyRange, Chr(10))
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    MyArray(i) = MyArray(i) & " Text" & i
Next i

MyRange = Join(MyArray, Chr(10))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this function:

```
Function AddText(rng As Range, textsArr As Variant) As String
    Dim nTexts As Long, nLines As Long, iLine As Long
    Dim linesArr As Variant

    nTexts = UBound(textsArr) - LBound(textsArr) + 1
    With rng
        linesArr = Split(.Value, vbLf)
        nLines = UBound(linesArr) - LBound(linesArr) + 1

        If nTexts < nLines Then nLines = nTexts

        For iLine = 1 To nLines
            linesArr(LBound(linesArr) - 1 + iLine) = linesArr(LBound(linesArr) - 1 + iLine) & " " & textsArr(LBound(textsArr) - 1 + iLine)
        Next iLine
        AddText = Join(linesArr, vbLf)
    End With
End Function
```

to be exploited as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim additionalTexts As Variant

    additionalTexts = Array("First Text", "Second Text", "Third Text", "Fourth Text") '<--| set your array of additional text, each element index corresponding to to be processed cell content line
    With Worksheets("ADDTEXT") '<--| reference your relevant worksheet (change "ADDTEXT" to your actual relevant worksheet name)
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "A" cells form row 1 down to last not empty row
            cell.Value = AddText(cell, additionalTexts) '<--| process
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will but in the text "First Line", "Second Line"... after each line. The way it is set up now uses the value in `A1` and replaces the value in `A1`. It is ideal for cells with 4 lines or less, but it will work with more.

```
Sub appendCharacters()

    Dim lines() As String
    Dim text As String

    lines = Split(Range("A1"), Chr(10))

    Range("A1").Value = ""

    For i = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
        Select Case i
            Case 0
                text = " First Line"
            Case 1
                text = " Second Line"
            Case 2
                text = " Third Line"
            Case 3
                text = " Fourth Line"
            Case Else
                text = " Another Line"
        End Select

        lines(i) = lines(i) + text

        Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + lines(i)
        If i <> UBound(lines) Then
            Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + vbCrLf
        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```